# parsing wikipedia stopwords html with nltk

Tags: python, nltk, text-parsing, wikipedia-api, stop-words

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259685/python-querying-wikipedia-performance) question, I am working on a program to extract the introduction of wikipedia entities. As you can read in the above link, I already succeeded to query the api and am now focussing on the processing of the xml returned by the api call. I use [nltk](http://nltk.org/) to process the xml, where I use

```
wikiwords = nltk.word_tokenize(introtext)
for wikiword in wikiwords:
    wikiword = lemmatizer.lemmatize(wikiword.lower())
    ...
```

But with this I end up having recorded words like `</`, `/p`, `<`, ... . Since I am not using the structure of the xml, simply ignoring all xml would work, I guess. Is there a tool of nltk or is there a stopwords list available. I would just like to know, what's best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what exact query are you using, but it seems what you have now is HTML, not XML, which you extracted from the XML response.

And if you want to strip all HTML tags from the HTML code and leave only the text, you should use HTML library for that, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I tried two different things. First, I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) answer of David Vuong, to simply remove the punctuations. This left words like `li` and `ul` in my dictionary. First I thought, working with yet another library would be overkill, but now I tried BeautifulSoup, which has a pretty function `soup.get_text()`. This works just great. Thanks again